# Make iAd banner disappear when no ad is shown ,swift

Tags: swift

Apple just rejected my app because when there are no ads shown the banner ad will become white and empty. Apparently you need to let the banner disappear when there is no ad. They send me a solution in Objective C, however I always write my apps in swift and am not proficient in Objective C. Could someone help me out here how to set it up so that the banner will disappear if no ad is shown. Appreciate the help. This is my code :

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import iAd

class StartUpViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var iAD: ADBannerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    iAD.delegate = self
    self.layoutScreen()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func layoutScreen() {
    var newBannerViewFrame = iAD.frame

    if iAD.bannerLoaded {
        // Show banner view
        let bannerHeight = iAD.frame.height
        let bannerY = self.view.bounds.height - bannerHeight
        newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bannerY, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: bannerHeight)
    } else {
        // Hide banner view
        newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: iAD.frame.height)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.iAD.frame = newBannerViewFrame
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.layoutScreen()
}
```

This is what Apple send me :

(APPLE'S COMMENT)
Next Steps

Please revise your app to implement a banner view delegate. This will hide the banner when ad content is not available.

An example code snippet is included here for your convenience:

Banner View Delegate to Remove a Banner View When Advertisements are Not Available:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:    (NSError *)error
{
if (self.bannerIsVisible)
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
// assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen.
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -   banner.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
```

EDIT :

I think I found a solution myself. It seems to work, but I'd like to be sure. Can anyone have a look at this code and confirm I'm doing it the right way.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    iAD.delegate = self
    iAD.hidden = true
    self.layoutScreen()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func layoutScreen() {
    var newBannerViewFrame = iAD.frame

    if iAD.bannerLoaded {
        // Show banner view
        let bannerHeight = iAD.frame.height
        let bannerY = self.view.bounds.height - bannerHeight
        newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bannerY, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: bannerHeight)
    } else {
        // Hide banner view
        newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: iAD.frame.height)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.iAD.frame = newBannerViewFrame
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.layoutScreen()
    iAD.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    iAD.hidden = true

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't try myself, but the given code can be *translated* into the following :

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class StartUpViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var iAD: ADBannerView!
    var bannerIsVisible : Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        iAD.delegate = self
        self.layoutScreen()
    }

    func layoutScreen() {
        var newBannerViewFrame = iAD.frame

        if (iAD.bannerLoaded) {
            // Show banner view
            let bannerHeight = iAD.frame.height
            let bannerY = self.view.bounds.height - bannerHeight
            newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bannerY, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: bannerHeight)
            self.bannerIsVisible = true
        } else {
            // Hide banner view
            newBannerViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: iAD.frame.height)
            self.bannerIsVisible = false
        }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.iAD.frame = newBannerViewFrame
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        if (self.bannerIsVisible) {
            UIView.beginAnimations("animateAdBannerOff", context: nil)
            // Assumes the banner view is at the top of the screen
            iAD.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -iAD.frame.size.height);
            UIView.commitAnimations()
            self.bannerIsVisible = false
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

You need to add a boolean property to keep track of your banner being visible or not.

Then, the method provided by Apple come from the `ADBannerViewDelegate`. Inside (called when the ad failed to load), you set up an animation in order to make your banner disappear if it was visible. The animation provided, as indicated in the comment inside, remove the banner if it was at the top of your view (if it is not the case, you need to adapt the line where you change the frame position).